# How to make n number of react.js countdown timers based on array filled with n milliseconds values in class based component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, react-component

The scenario of question is

**suppose varArray = [150000,1900000,...,n] is given and we have to initialize n count down timers in this case and show the timers in a division of render method.**

I am new to react.js so can you please help in explanatory way.

I am using class based component, it would be very helpful if you would answer in this perspective.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you trying to display a countdown to the user?

Comment: Make a countdown component which takes the starting ms as a prop. Have the parent component map over your array and create an instance of the countdown component for each ms value in the array.

Answer (score 0):

this should do it

```
const arr=[150000,1900000], timers = [];

arr.forEach( 
    (ms, index) => { 
        timers.push( 
            setTimeout(function(){ 
                console.log(`timer ${index} is done`); 
            },
            ms
        ) 
})
```